# How do I make shape rotate on its axis?

Tags: ios, swift

The hexagon rotates, but it wont stay in place and rotate. What do I need to change in order for it to spin clockwise once every single time the button is clicked.

```
    shape6 = CAShapeLayer()
    view.layer.addSublayer(shape6)
    shape6.opacity = 0.5
    shape6.lineWidth = 2
    shape6.lineJoin = kCALineJoinMiter
    shape6.strokeColor = UIColor(hue: 0.786, saturation: 0.79, brightness: 0.53, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    shape6.fillColor = UIColor(hue: 0, saturation: 0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0).CGColor

    path6 = UIBezierPath()
    path6.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(35,430))
    path6.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(80, 300))
    path6.closePath()
    shape6.path = path6.CGPath


@IBAction func ispin(sender: AnyObject) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: ({
        self.shape1.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30, 150, 400, 20)
        self.shape2.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30, 150, 400, 20)
        self.shape3.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30, 150, 400, 20)
        self.shape4.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30, 150, 400, 20)
        self.shape5.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30, 150, 400, 20)
        self.shape6.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(30, 150, 400, 20)
    }))

}
```

Comment: what do you mean it's dose not stay on its place ?

Comment: It moves to a different location, but I want it to stay in one place and every time the button is clicked the hexagon will rotate x degrees and stay in the same place. It won't move on the x,y, or z axis.

Comment: post a picture for your constraints and I will help you

Comment: The constraints I currently have are above

Comment: can you upload a video of the animation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the anchor point of the shape `shape6`:

```
shape6.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
```